# hyperledger-composer ParseException: Except "namespace", comment, end of line or whitespace but "ir" found

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I have the following code and am receiving a `ParseException: Except "namespace", comment, end of line or whitespace but "ir" found`

io.company.network.cto

```
import io.company.network.Member
namespace io.company.network
participant Person identified by email {
   o String email
   --> Member members
}
```

io.company.network.member.cto

```
namespace io.company.network.member
abstract Members {
    o String firstname
    o String lastname
}
participant Member identified by email extends Members {
    o String email
}
```

The problem is when try to compile with the next line:

`composer archive create -t dir -n .`

I'm not sure why it's happening.

Thanks

Comment: You might want to try using composer playground to help you find and fix problems
http://composer-playground.mybluemix.net/

Comment: You should import `io.company.network.member.Member` instead of `io.company.network.Member`

Comment: Thanks, i had can resolved.